# Whats wrong with ZK viewport meta?

Tags: java, tablet, zk

i migrated a project from zk5 to zk6.5.1.
The most is fine except the viewport on tablet device. Its the same meta as before but the tablet does scale the page in the early version and now the page will be croped. Crop => left on the page is a grey area without content this is the meta:

```
<?meta name="viewport" content="width=1000; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;" ?>
```

anyone know this effect? and how to solve that?

Tablet device: Samsung Galxay GT-P7500, Android 3.1

Answer (score 0):

Viewport meta is buggy in this version of android 3.1.
Got two Tablets but the other one was with 3.2 there it works! *grml*